# How to add text into a link in src=" "

Tags: html, django, model

I have this src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/1Go9q6KaCpAsQ0wkZFGzY2?utm_source=generator" and I want it to be like this src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/{{ spotify_trackid }}?utm_source=generator"

how can I do this using django without it breaking the link?

sorry for the bad explanation i'm pretty new to this

Comment: please give us a template and view - where you want to change your spotify_trackid. it is really hard to imagine was and where you want to do it.

Comment: I figured it out sorry for not being exact

Answer (score -2):

You should use href attribute to add links to your text like this:

```
<a href="https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/1Go9q6KaCpAsQ0wkZFGzY2?utm_source=generator">Your Text</a>
```

And you can't play with URL of websites